# PHPStorm panes behaviour

Tags: phpstorm, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have switched to PHPStorm from ST3 recently and there is something that I can't get used to.

When you use panes and close the last tab in that pane, the pane is closed, unlike in ST3 it's still open.

What can be done to keep it open regardless of the open tabs? I want to mimic the whole ST3+Origami package in PHPStorm as it's really powerful and user friendly for a heavy keyboard user.

Comment: What "panes" are you talking about? Screenshots please.

Comment: @LazyOne https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently that is not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66407 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified about progress.